# Plugin Registration Tool and remote debug

Tags: debugging, plugins, dynamics-crm, workflow, crm

I am beginner in crm, could somebody tell me advantage or disadvantage of using remote debugger in crm. Should I use Registration Tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the information here:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmbusiness/archive/2015/11/19/crm-2013-step-by-step-guide-to-remote-debugging

The reasons why we need to use this tool or the tool's functions, we could think that what the advantage of this tool. The considerations during using this tools or others, you could also get detailed information from the above document. Of course, it also shared the detailed steps about how/when we can use this tool. About whether you should use this tool, it is really related to your current requirements:)

Answer (score 0):

The Plugin Registration Tool is a simple way of registering your custom code with the CRM system. With this tool you can connect to your CRM organisation and register your plugins to execute on specific events within the system, such as creation or updating of specific attributes on different records, while the Remote Debugger greatly reduces the amount of time in debugging your plugins by allowing you to step through your code remotely as it executes.

You can find a detailed guide to the Plugin Registration Tool on MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309580(v=crm.5).aspx

There is also an in-depth guide to the Remote Debugger (CRM 2013, also applies to CRM 2016) here: https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/crm-2013-step-by-step-guide-to-remote-debugging/